# How to git diff between two versions of the same file within the same branch using Tortoise?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am a recent convert from using an IDE to using Sublime. One of the things that was really useful to me via IDE was their diff tools. For instance in RubyMine you could see the two files next to each other, and color-highlights of the lines that were added/removed.

In Sublime, I was able to install the git package via the package installer and git diff within Sublime. But it still doesn't give me the nice side-by-side view of the +/- lines. I'm wondering how to do this via TortoiseGit Diff. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your global `.gitconfig` (e.g. by doing `git config --global --edit`)

```
[diff]
    tool = tortoisediff
[difftool "tortoisediff"]
    cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -mine:"$REMOTE" -base:"$LOCAL"
```

Then the command `git difftool` will give you side-by-side diffs in TortoiseGit.

If you want to use TortoiseGit for merging too, you can add:

```
[merge]
    tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
    cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"
```

And merge with `git mergetool`

Comment: thanks, that brings up tortoise git  but it says 'cannot display image'. Why is it trying to display an image and not text?

Comment: @justclaire Use `TortoiseGitMerge.exe` instead of `TortoiseGitIDiff.exe`

Comment: In my case, when trying to do `git difftool` it shows both sides empty :\ Instead, `git mergetool` works like a charm